# group concat different rows

Tags: mysql, sql

```
name   type   shape
---------------------
name1  type1  shape1
name1  type2  shape1
name1  type3  shape2
```

after query i need that result:

```
name    shape1Types     shape2Types
-----------------------------------
name1   type1, type2    type3
```

i can only think as much:

```
select name, group_concat(type) as shape1Types, group_concat(type) as shape2Types 
from table 
where name = 'name1' 
  and shape1Types in (select type from table2 where shape = 'shape1') 
  and shape2Times in (select type from table3 where shape = 'shape2') 
group by name
```

but here it says shape1Types is unknown column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below by using case when

```
   select name, group_concat(case when shape='shape1' then type end) as shape1Types, group_concat(case when shape='shape2' then type end) as shape2Types 
    from table 
    group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

The alias names shape1Types & shape2Types are unknown in that WHERE clause.
Hence the error.

Instead of using `IN` you could `JOIN` to the unique types in those other 2 tables.

```
select 
 t.name, 
 group_concat(shape1.type) as shape1Types, 
 group_concat(shape2.type) as shape2Types 
from table1 t
left join (select type from table2 where shape = 'shape1' group by type) shape1 
  on shape1.type = t.type
left join (select type from table3 where shape = 'shape2' group by type) shape2 
  on shape2.type = t.type
where t.name = 'name1'
-- and (shape1.type is not null or shape2.type is not null)
group by t.name
```